# Android App now takes 15 seconds to launch

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services, in-app-billing

My app use to take less than a second to launch but it now sometimes takes up to 15 seconds. I've noticed this in the past few weeks since Android "O" was released but this could be a coincidence since the delay now also happens on older devices that have not been updated to "O".

I use AdMob, GooglePlayServices, InAppBilling, CloudSave, Leaderboards, Achievements and a Google+1 button in my app. It seems that the logcat with the delay is querying all sorts of things I didn't ask for: Wifi state, battery service, AlarmManager, TextClock, WeatherWidget etc.

Any ideas what is causing this delay and how to stop it?

Logcat with no delay:

```
06-25 21:28:58.961 3648-14751/? D/AudioService: getStreamVolume 3 index 0
06-25 21:28:58.963 3648-3661/? D/AudioService: getStreamVolume 2 index 80
06-25 21:28:58.964 3648-4623/? D/AudioService: getStreamVolume 2 index 80
06-25 21:28:58.999 5475-7496/? I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
06-25 21:28:58.999 5475-7496/? I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
06-25 21:28:59.006 3648-5036/? D/WindowManager: finishDrawingWindow: Window{7a43544d0 u0 com.package.app/com.package.app.screens.MyActivity} mDrawState=DRAW_PENDING
06-25 21:28:59.008 3648-14751/? V/WindowManager: Relayout Window{4e97536d0 u0 com.package.app/com.package.app.screens.MyActivity}: viewVisibility=0 req=1080x1920 WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(fillxfill) sim=#120 ty=1 fl=#1810500 pfl=0x20000 fmt=-3 wanim=0x1030001 vsysui=0x400 needsMenuKey=2 naviIconColor=0}
06-25 21:28:59.010 7411-7411/? D/ViewRootImpl@5c49873[MyActivity]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][1080,1920] newFrame=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x1 surface={isValid=true 537800327680} surfaceGenerationChanged=false
06-25 21:28:59.013 5475-7497/? I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
06-25 21:28:59.013 5475-7497/? I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false


======= problem normally from here =======


06-25 21:28:59.287 3648-5121/? D/CustomFrequencyManagerService: releaseDVFSLockLocked : Getting Lock type frm List : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 2100000  uid : 1000  pid : 3648  tag : APP_LAUNCH@CPU_MIN@804
06-25 21:28:59.423 3648-5260/? V/WindowManager: Relayout Window{c6f7810d0 u0 SurfaceView - com.package.app/com.package.app.screens.MyActivity}: viewVisibility=0 req=1080x1920 WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(1080x1920) gr=#800033 ty=1001 fl=#4218 pfl=0x10040 fmt=4 naviIconColor=0}
06-25 21:28:59.426 7411-7411/? D/SurfaceView: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][1080,1920] newFrame=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x1 surface={Surface(name=null)/@0x806cc23 isValid=true 537272335872}
06-25 21:28:59.426 3648-4833/? D/WindowManager: finishDrawingWindow: Window{c6f7810d0 u0 SurfaceView - com.package.app/com.package.app.screens.MyActivity} mDrawState=READY_TO_SHOW
06-25 21:28:59.429 3097-3823/? I/Layer: [com.package.app/com.package.app.screens.MyActivity] addSyncPoint start
06-25 21:28:59.429 3097-3823/? I/Layer: [com.package.app/com.package.app.screens.MyActivity] addSyncPoint end
06-25 21:28:59.429 3097-3823/? I/Layer: [com.package.app/com.package.app.screens.MyActivity] addSyncPoint start
06-25 21:28:59.429 3097-3823/? I/Layer: [com.package.app/com.package.app.screens.MyActivity] addSyncPoint end
06-25 21:28:59.452 3648-3838/? D/WindowManager: finishDrawingWindow: Window{4e97536d0 u0 com.package.app/com.package.app.screens.MyActivity} mDrawState=DRAW_PENDING
06-25 21:28:59.453 7411-7411/? D/ViewRootImpl@a04fec8[MyActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
06-25 21:28:59.453 7411-7411/? D/ViewRootImpl@5c49873[MyActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
06-25 21:28:59.453 7411-7411/? V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@ed3309e nm : com.package.app ic=null
06-25 21:28:59.454 3097-3823/? I/Layer: [com.package.app/com.package.app.screens.MyActivity] addSyncPoint start
06-25 21:28:59.454 3097-3823/? I/Layer: [com.package.app/com.package.app.screens.MyActivity] addSyncPoint end
06-25 21:28:59.454 3097-3823/? I/Layer: [com.package.app/com.package.app.screens.MyActivity] addSyncPoint start
06-25 21:28:59.454 3097-3823/? I/Layer: [com.package.app/com.package.app.screens.MyActivity] addSyncPoint end


========= ok from here ============

06-25 21:28:59.454 7411-7411/? D/MyActivity: Query inventory finished.
06-25 21:28:59.454 7411-7411/? D/MyActivity: Query inventory was successful.


06-25 21:28:59.454 7411-7411/? D/MyActivity: Initial inventory query finished.
06-25 21:28:59.457 3648-3675/? D/KnoxTimeoutHandler: notifyActivityDrawn [MsgParam] userId: 0 fullscreen is true showWhenlocked is false isMutiwindowRecord is false multiwindowstyle is 1
06-25 21:28:59.457 3648-3648/? D/KnoxTimeoutHandler: activityDrawn [MsgParam] userId: 0 fullscreen is true showWhenlocked is false isMutiwindowRecord is false multiwindowstyle is 1
06-25 21:28:59.458 3648-3648/? I/KnoxTimeoutHandler: SD activityfalse
06-25 21:28:59.458 3648-3675/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.package.app/.screens.MyActivity: +1s4ms (total +1s147ms)
06-25 21:28:59.458 3648-3648/? I/KnoxTimeoutHandler: Fullscreen and mCurrent is not KNOX user. Hence hide keyguard
06-25 21:28:59.459 5475-5494/? W/GamesServiceBroker: Client connected with SDK 11010000, Services 11055440, and Games 39080040
```

Logcat with delay:

```
06-23 22:39:53.300 3649-5919/? D/AudioService: getStreamVolume 3 index 0
06-23 22:39:53.301 3649-5037/? D/CompatibilityInfo: mCompatibilityFlags - 0
06-23 22:39:53.301 3649-5037/? D/CompatibilityInfo: applicationDensity - 640
06-23 22:39:53.301 3649-5037/? D/CompatibilityInfo: applicationScale - 1.0
06-23 22:39:53.302 3649-5918/? D/AudioService: getStreamVolume 2 index 80
06-23 22:39:53.310 3649-10303/? D/AudioService: getStreamVolume 3 index 0
06-23 22:39:53.311 3649-10301/? D/AudioService: getStreamVolume 2 index 80
06-23 22:39:53.328 3649-17042/? D/WindowManager: finishDrawingWindow: Window{a3e0fdcd0 u0 com.package.app/com.package.app.screens.MyActivity} mDrawState=DRAW_PENDING
06-23 22:39:53.334 3649-29658/? V/WindowManager: Relayout Window{a18840ed0 u0 com.package.app/com.package.app.screens.MyActivity}: viewVisibility=0 req=1080x1920 WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(fillxfill) sim=#120 ty=1 fl=#1810500 pfl=0x20000 fmt=-3 wanim=0x1030001 vsysui=0x400 needsMenuKey=2 naviIconColor=0}
06-23 22:39:53.336 25516-25516/? D/ViewRootImpl@801a4c4[MyActivity]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][1080,1920] newFrame=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x1 surface={isValid=true 543290605056} surfaceGenerationChanged=false
06-23 22:39:53.341 6206-25602/? I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
06-23 22:39:53.341 6206-25602/? I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
06-23 22:39:53.363 6206-25607/? I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
06-23 22:39:53.363 6206-25607/? I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false


====problem here======


06-23 22:39:53.657 3649-3845/? D/CustomFrequencyManagerService: releaseDVFSLockLocked : Getting Lock type frm List : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 2100000  uid : 1000  pid : 3649  tag : APP_LAUNCH@CPU_MIN@54

06-23 22:39:54.290 4774-4774/? D/io_stats: !@   8,0 r 13963419 457889932 w 3912223 73429696 d 416689 40745824 f 1281947 1281760 iot 7052090 4676990 th 61440 61440 53432 pt 1540 inp 0 0 285600.448
06-23 22:39:54.917 3649-3850/? D/WifiStateMachine: Current network is: "xxxxxxxxxx" , ID is: 4
06-23 22:39:54.917 3649-3850/? D/WifiStateMachine: 24GHz mQnsUpperRssiThreshold is recovered, currentRssi = -74
06-23 22:39:55.666 3649-4850/? D/ActivityManagerPerformance: Received DISABLE_MSG_APP_SWITCH, r: ActivityRecord{acafc49d0 u0 com.package.app/.screens.SplashActivity t1084 f}
06-23 22:39:55.667 3649-4850/? D/CustomFrequencyManagerService: acquireDVFSLockLocked : type : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 1800000  uid : 1000  pid : 3649  pkgName : AMS_RESUME_TAIL@CPU_MIN@19
06-23 22:39:55.667 3649-4850/? D/ActivityManagerPerformance: AMP_acquire() TAIL
06-23 22:39:55.667 3649-4850/? D/CustomFrequencyManagerService: releaseDVFSLockLocked : Getting Lock type frm List : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 2100000  uid : 1000  pid : 3649  tag : AMS_APP_SWITCH@CPU_MIN@13
06-23 22:39:55.667 3649-4850/? D/ActivityManagerPerformance: AMP_release() APP_SWITCH
06-23 22:39:55.967 3649-3649/? D/CustomFrequencyManagerService: releaseDVFSLockLocked : Getting Lock type frm List : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 1800000  uid : 1000  pid : 3649  tag : AMS_RESUME_TAIL@CPU_MIN@19
06-23 22:39:56.169 3649-7115/? D/TelephonyManager: getAllCellInfo : Caller (PID / UID / TID): 3649 / 1000 / 7115
06-23 22:39:57.926 3649-3850/? D/WifiStateMachine: Current network is: "xxxxxxxxxx" , ID is: 4
06-23 22:39:58.206 3649-5184/? D/BatteryService: !@BatteryListener : batteryPropertiesChanged!
06-23 22:39:58.206 3649-5184/? D/BatteryService: level:48, scale:100, status:2, health:2, present:true, voltage: 3863, temperature: 286, technology: Li-ion, AC powered:false, USB powered:true, POGO powered:false, Wireless powered:false, icon:17303690, invalid charger:0, maxChargingCurrent:0, maxChargingVoltage:0, chargeCounter:0
06-23 22:39:58.206 3649-5184/? D/BatteryService: online:4, current avg:83, charge type:1, power sharing:false, high voltage charger:false, capacity:280000, batterySWSelfDischarging:false, misc_event:0, current_now:183
06-23 22:39:58.206 3649-3649/? D/BatteryService: Sending ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED.
06-23 22:39:58.207 3649-3649/? V/UiModeManager: updateLocked: null action, mDockState=0, category=null
06-23 22:39:58.207 3649-3649/? D/UiModeManager: updateConfigurationLocked: mDockState=0; mCarMode=false; mNightMode=1; uiMode=17
06-23 22:39:58.207 3649-3649/? D/GameManagerService: new battery level: 48
06-23 22:39:58.208 4011-4011/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: received broadcast android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
06-23 22:39:58.209 4011-4011/? D/PowerUI: priorPlugType = 2 mPlugType =  2
06-23 22:39:58.209 4011-4011/? D/PowerUI.Notification: showChargingNotice oldChargingType : 1 currentChargingType : 1 oldChargingTime : 11438000 mChargingTime : 11438000
06-23 22:39:58.209 4011-4011/? D/PowerUI.Notification: There is no change about charging status, so return!
06-23 22:39:58.209 4011-4011/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: handleBatteryUpdate
06-23 22:39:58.211 4011-4011/? D/BatteryMeterDrawable: isSomethingChanged - false
06-23 22:39:58.211 4011-4011/? D/BatteryMeterDrawable: isSomethingChanged - false
06-23 22:39:58.212 4011-4011/? D/Tile.FlashlightTile: ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED - Level :: 48, emEnabled :: false
06-23 22:39:59.291 4774-4774/? D/io_stats: !@   8,0 r 13963419 457889932 w 3912276 73430180 d 416691 40745832 f 1281950 1281763 iot 7052110 4677008 th 61440 61440 53432 pt 1540 inp 0 0 285605.449
06-23 22:39:59.822 4011-4232/? D/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(0/1): onSignalStrengthsChanged signalStrength=SignalStrength: 0 99 -4 -200 -4 -200 -1 99 -109 -10 30 2 2147483647 0x2000 gsm|lte level=2
06-23 22:39:59.822 4011-4232/? D/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(0/1): getMobileIconGroup(): 13
06-23 22:39:59.824 4011-4232/? D/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(0/1): onSignalStrengthsChanged signalStrength=SignalStrength: 2 99 -2 -200 -2 -200 -1 2 -109 -10 30 2 2147483647 0x2000 gsm|lte level=2
06-23 22:39:59.824 4011-4232/? D/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(0/1): getMobileIconGroup(): 13
06-23 22:40:00.000 3649-3774/? D/SamsungAlarmManager: Expired : 4
06-23 22:40:00.001 3649-3774/? D/SamsungAlarmManager: setInexact Intent (T:1/F:0/AC:false) 20170623T224200 - CU:1000/CP:3649
06-23 22:40:00.001 3649-3774/? I/SamsungAlarmManager: setLocked to kernel - T:2 / 20170623T224001, SetElapsed=1128273895, nowELAPSED=1128271922
06-23 22:40:00.001 3649-3774/? V/SamsungAlarmManager: Sending to uid : 1000 action=android.intent.action.TIME_TICK alarm=Alarm{feaab72 type 3 when 1128271922 android}
06-23 22:40:00.006 3649-3774/? V/SamsungAlarmManager: Sending to uid : 10015 action=com.google.android.location.ALARM_WAKEUP_LOCATOR alarm=Alarm{353ebc3 type 2 when 1128244604 com.google.android.gms}
06-23 22:40:00.006 3649-3774/? V/SamsungAlarmManager: Sending to uid : 10015 action=com.google.android.location.internal.action.ULR_BAROMETER_READ_ALARM alarm=Alarm{862fc40 type 1 when 1498254000000 com.google.android.gms}
06-23 22:40:00.007 3649-3774/? D/SamsungAlarmManager: Expired : 8
06-23 22:40:00.009 3649-3649/? D/SamsungAlarmManager: setExact Intent (T:3/F:1/AC:false) 20170623T224100 - CU:1000/CP:3649
06-23 22:40:00.010 3649-3774/? E/AlarmManager: No more alarm at this time. nowELAPSED=1128271929 batch.start=1128273895 mNextWakeup=1128273895 mNextNonWakeup=1128271922 mAlarmBatches.size=54
06-23 22:40:00.010 3649-3774/? E/AlarmManager: Batch 1 size = 1 : 1128273895, Batch 2 size = 1 : 1128302704, Batch 3 size = 3 : 1128318539
06-23 22:40:00.010 3649-3774/? I/SamsungAlarmManager: setLocked to kernel - T:2 / 20170623T224001, SetElapsed=1128273895, nowELAPSED=1128271931
06-23 22:40:00.010 4011-4011/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: received broadcast android.intent.action.TIME_TICK
06-23 22:40:00.010 4011-4011/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: handleTimeUpdate#start
06-23 22:40:00.010 4011-4011/? I/KeyguardClockPage: refreshTime(): DefaultSingle2016 hometime:Europe/London locale:en_GB hasBG?false, Roaming:false
06-23 22:40:00.011 3649-5021/? E/Sensors: Pressure old sensor_state 16384, new sensor_state : 16416 en : 1
06-23 22:40:00.013 4878-4878/? D/SensorManager: registerListener :: 4, LPS25H Barometer Sensor, 0, 0,  
06-23 22:40:00.015 4011-4011/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: handleTimeUpdate#end
06-23 22:40:00.016 3649-10304/? D/SamsungAlarmManager: setExact Intent (T:2/F:1/AC:false) 20170623T224005 - CU:10015/CP:4878
06-23 22:40:00.016 4878-5453/? D/TelephonyManager: getAllCellInfo : Caller (PID / UID / TID): 4878 / 10015 / 5453
06-23 22:40:00.018 3649-3877/? E/wifi: failed to get channel list : -95
06-23 22:40:00.023 4011-4011/? D/SystemUI_Clock: Clock received ACTION_TIME_TICK : start
06-23 22:40:00.024 3649-3877/? W/CAE: setCAProperty(ContextAwareService.java:589) - [setProperty 01] Mutex is locked for ANY_MOTION_DETECTOR_RUNNER
06-23 22:40:00.025 3649-3877/? I/CAE: sendCmdToSensorHub(SensorHubCommManager.java:162) - -72, 58, 1, 0,
06-23 22:40:00.025 3649-3877/? D/SensorHubManager: SendSensorHubData: send data = -72, 58, 1, 0
06-23 22:40:00.025 3109-3109/? D/Sensorhubs: sendContextData: -72, 58, 1, 0
06-23 22:40:00.026 4011-4011/? D/SystemUI_Clock: Clock received ACTION_TIME_TICK : end
06-23 22:40:00.028 3649-3877/? I/CAE: setCAProperty(ContextAwareService.java:594) - result : true
06-23 22:40:00.028 3649-3877/? W/CAE: setCAProperty(ContextAwareService.java:595) - [setProperty 02] Mutex is unlocked for ANY_MOTION_DETECTOR_RUNNER
06-23 22:40:00.028 3649-3877/? D/SemContextService: requestToUpdate() : service = Any Motion Detector
06-23 22:40:00.028 3649-3877/? D/SemContextManager:   .requestToUpdate : listener = android.hardware.scontext.SContextManager$SContextListenerDelegate@2362fd, service=Any Motion Detector
06-23 22:40:00.041 4011-4011/? D/TextClock: TextClock received ACTION_TIME_TICK : start
06-23 22:40:00.041 4011-4011/? D/TextClock: TextClock received ACTION_TIME_TICK : end
06-23 22:40:00.042 4011-4011/? D/TextClock: TextClock received ACTION_TIME_TICK : start
06-23 22:40:00.043 4011-4011/? D/TextClock: TextClock received ACTION_TIME_TICK : end
06-23 22:40:00.048 3109-3159/? D/Sensorhubs: readContextData: 1, 1, 58, 0
06-23 22:40:00.049 3649-3781/? D/SensorHubManager: onGetSensorHubDataLocked: library(4) = 1, 1, 58, 0
06-23 22:40:00.049 3649-3780/? D/CAE: onGetSensorHubData(SensorHubParserProvider.java:94) - onGetSensorHubData Event [event buffer len :4], AP_WAKEUP
06-23 22:40:00.049 3649-3780/? I/CAE: parse(SensorHubParserProvider.java:196) - buffer size = 4
06-23 22:40:00.049 3649-3780/? I/CAE: parse(SensorHubParserProvider.java:207) - 1, 1, 58, 0,
06-23 22:40:00.050 3649-3780/? D/CAE: display(ContextProvider.java:375) - ================= ANY_MOTION_DETECTOR_RUNNER =================
06-23 22:40:00.050 3649-3780/? I/CAE: display(ContextProvider.java:391) - Action=[0]
06-23 22:40:00.050 3649-3783/? D/SemContextService: updateContext() : event = Any Motion Detector
06-23 22:40:00.050 3649-3859/? D/SemContextManager: onSemContextChanged() : event = Any Motion Detector
06-23 22:40:00.050 3649-3859/? D/SContextManager: onSContextChanged() : event = Any Motion Detector
06-23 22:40:00.058 4011-4011/? D/TextClock: TextClock received ACTION_TIME_TICK : start
06-23 22:40:00.058 4011-4011/? D/TextClock: TextClock received ACTION_TIME_TICK : end
06-23 22:40:00.059 4011-4011/? V/hong: mid yDiff = 584
06-23 22:40:00.059 4011-4011/? V/hong: mid yDiff = 584
06-23 22:40:00.075 4011-4011/? D/SystemUI_DateView: DateView received ACTION_TIME_TICK : start
06-23 22:40:00.075 4011-4011/? D/SystemUI_DateView: DateView received ACTION_TIME_TICK : end
06-23 22:40:00.075 4011-4011/? V/hong: mid yDiff = 584
06-23 22:40:00.075 4011-4011/? V/hong: mid yDiff = 584
06-23 22:40:00.076 4011-4011/? D/TextClock: TextClock received ACTION_TIME_TICK : start
06-23 22:40:00.077 4011-4011/? D/TextClock: TextClock received ACTION_TIME_TICK : end
06-23 22:40:00.078 4011-4011/? D/TextClock: TextClock received ACTION_TIME_TICK : start
06-23 22:40:00.078 4011-4011/? D/TextClock: TextClock received ACTION_TIME_TICK : end
06-23 22:40:00.079 4011-4011/? D/DateTimeView: DateTimeView received ACTION_TIME_TICK : start
06-23 22:40:00.079 4011-4011/? D/DateTimeView: DateTimeView received ACTION_TIME_TICK : end
06-23 22:40:00.080 19146-19146/? D/TextClock: TextClock received ACTION_TIME_TICK : start
06-23 22:40:00.081 19146-19146/? D/TextClock: TextClock received ACTION_TIME_TICK : end
06-23 22:40:00.082 19146-19146/? D/TextClock: TextClock received ACTION_TIME_TICK : start
06-23 22:40:00.082 19146-19146/? D/TextClock: TextClock received ACTION_TIME_TICK : end
06-23 22:40:00.083 19146-19146/? D/TextClock: TextClock received ACTION_TIME_TICK : start
06-23 22:40:00.083 19146-19146/? D/TextClock: TextClock received ACTION_TIME_TICK : end
06-23 22:40:00.084 19146-19146/? D/TextClock: TextClock received ACTION_TIME_TICK : start
06-23 22:40:00.084 19146-19146/? D/TextClock: TextClock received ACTION_TIME_TICK : end
06-23 22:40:00.089 19146-19146/? V/LauncherAppWidgetHostView: calculateWidgetSize: (target widgetsize)  using w/h 1372 440 span 4 1 (widgetid 2) [current Gridsize : GRID_4x4]
06-23 22:40:00.090 19146-19146/? D/LauncherAppWidgetHostView: calculateWidgetSize() widget = Weather and Clock(widget id = 2) result hostview size = 1372 x 440
06-23 22:40:00.090 19146-19146/? D/LauncherAppWidgetHostView: setResizeScaleResult() 1372/ 440 scaleToResize = 1.0(widget id = 2)
06-23 22:40:00.090 19146-19146/? V/LauncherAppWidgetHostView: calculateWidgetSize: (target widgetsize)  using w/h 1372 440 span 4 1 (widgetid 3) [current Gridsize : GRID_4x4]
06-23 22:40:00.090 19146-19146/? D/LauncherAppWidgetHostView: calculateWidgetSize() widget = Google(widget id = 3) result hostview size = 1372 x 440
06-23 22:40:00.090 19146-19146/? D/LauncherAppWidgetHostView: setResizeScaleResult() 1372/ 440 scaleToResize = 1.0(widget id = 3)
06-23 22:40:00.091 19146-19146/? D/TextClock: TextClock received ACTION_TIME_TICK : start
06-23 22:40:00.091 19146-19146/? D/TextClock: TextClock received ACTION_TIME_TICK : end
06-23 22:40:00.092 3649-5919/? E/Sensors: Pressure old sensor_state 16416, new sensor_state : 16384 en : 0
06-23 22:40:00.092 19146-19146/? D/TextClock: TextClock received ACTION_TIME_TICK : start
06-23 22:40:00.092 19146-19146/? D/TextClock: TextClock received ACTION_TIME_TICK : end
06-23 22:40:00.093 4878-4878/? D/SensorManager: unregisterListener ::   
06-23 22:40:00.094 19146-19146/? D/TextClock: TextClock received ACTION_TIME_TICK : start
06-23 22:40:00.094 19146-19146/? D/TextClock: TextClock received ACTION_TIME_TICK : end
06-23 22:40:00.106 19146-19146/? V/LauncherAppWidgetHostView: calculateWidgetSize: (target widgetsize)  using w/h 1372 440 span 4 1 (widgetid 2) [current Gridsize : GRID_4x4]
06-23 22:40:00.106 19146-19146/? D/LauncherAppWidgetHostView: calculateWidgetSize() widget = Weather and Clock(widget id = 2) result hostview size = 1372 x 440
06-23 22:40:00.106 19146-19146/? D/LauncherAppWidgetHostView: setResizeScaleResult() 1372/ 440 scaleToResize = 1.0(widget id = 2)
06-23 22:40:00.107 19146-19146/? V/LauncherAppWidgetHostView: calculateWidgetSize: (target widgetsize)  using w/h 1372 440 span 4 1 (widgetid 3) [current Gridsize : GRID_4x4]
06-23 22:40:00.107 19146-19146/? D/LauncherAppWidgetHostView: calculateWidgetSize() widget = Google(widget id = 3) result hostview size = 1372 x 440
06-23 22:40:00.107 19146-19146/? D/LauncherAppWidgetHostView: setResizeScaleResult() 1372/ 440 scaleToResize = 1.0(widget id = 3)
06-23 22:40:00.107 19146-19146/? D/TextClock: TextClock received ACTION_TIME_TICK : start
06-23 22:40:00.107 19146-19146/? D/TextClock: TextClock received ACTION_TIME_TICK : end
06-23 22:40:00.108 19146-19146/? D/TextClock: TextClock received ACTION_TIME_TICK : start
06-23 22:40:00.108 19146-19146/? D/TextClock: TextClock received ACTION_TIME_TICK : end
06-23 22:40:00.111 19558-19558/? D/[WeatherWidget(1404)]  WeatherService: {[B73D43639EB27FAA34EF41A6129C1FA7EB7C69B2413A882B51D740D673E9232A546D20833562A945E90153AD6347B3D5D64657F32B2AA3FC1BFAEE665D8B0581]}
06-23 22:40:00.111 19558-19558/? D/[WeatherWidget(1404)]: {[3AE6950019B083611567B0F9442DB03E0CFD4B9B94C7886DA9F9793DD8C1B4F2]}
06-23 22:40:00.113 19558-19558/? D/[WeatherWidget(1404)]: {[236FFFA4FE6D378EDABD8749C406D4B623A9033B6C82EC1F6350A42D68D2E0CC94B6985FBB6EC3E92BF375BC4CBB0183A926513A5FAFAD6FA35C0BB54CE136B6]}
06-23 22:40:00.114 19558-19558/? D/[WeatherWidget(1404)]: {[236FFFA4FE6D378EDABD8749C406D4B6230C51D0EE18850996C7395F72B13F63ED08461A816138AC3B57431D5932500FFD2BDB71BCDFFB44C94BB7690874631DBD8C9D99478A214C814CA97B13DC24ACCBFD065762E6FC9CDCD193C7BAF654F7]}
06-23 22:40:00.118 19558-19558/? D/[WeatherWidget(1404)]: {[3AE6950019B083611567B0F9442DB03E2AF82806445486197707CC8654A1FF07094BFFD987D8BE2D52861B867EC92EF305409514A4C3971461FF804B10EE09E993C160A2B69032C625FA49775DB62D03]}
06-23 22:40:00.118 19558-19558/? D/[WeatherWidget(1404)]: {[A1AF0F6A1A65A89C43D705938923D0FEAE7CBA118D77CBAEE371C39D5B3A5D2896DCAEA9F69E652337891F3DD0F999682DE03DF95F63E55DC507ABEEB1184F3E5C7493FFA05DFAA2B94F26C5B2A53D77EE90E056602BE3AFAC39DA4962858EF32B0FB529AEFF987A7CB64F0AA4B678D0]}
06-23 22:40:00.119 19558-19558/? D/[WeatherWidget(1404)]: {[CBE90F3EF23DAF7447FA950223C7E0849EC1C379F8C5CEFDE6152E98A1BB9160]}
06-23 22:40:00.128 3649-3877/? D/WifiScanningService: time diff: 4140516
06-23 22:40:00.129 11231-11231/? I/wpa_supplicant: wlan0: Setting scan request: 0 sec 0 usec
06-23 22:40:00.129 11231-11231/? I/wpa_supplicant: P2P: Current p2p state = IDLE
06-23 22:40:00.136 3649-3877/? D/SamsungAlarmManager: setInexact Listener (T:2/F:8/AC:false) 20170623T224015 - CU:1000/CP:3649
06-23 22:40:00.136 11231-11231/? I/wpa_supplicant: Scan requested (ret=0) - scan timeout 30 seconds
06-23 22:40:00.782 3649-7115/? D/SSRM:l: SIOP:: AP = 350, PST = 324 (W:10), CP = 258, CUR = 84, LCD = 30
06-23 22:40:00.804 11231-11231/? I/wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Received scan results (3 BSSes)
06-23 22:40:00.805 3134-3636/? D/Netd: Iface wlan0 link up
06-23 22:40:00.805 3649-3877/? D/SamsungAlarmManager: Cancel Alarm calling from uid:1000 pid :3649 / listener:android.app.AlarmManager$ListenerWrapper@4811779
06-23 22:40:00.805 3649-3672/? D/Tethering: interfaceLinkStateChanged wlan0, true
06-23 22:40:00.805 3649-3672/? D/Tethering: interfaceStatusChanged wlan0, true
06-23 22:40:00.809 3649-3666/? D/CompatibilityInfo: mCompatibilityFlags - 0
06-23 22:40:00.809 3649-3666/? D/CompatibilityInfo: applicationDensity - 640
06-23 22:40:00.809 3649-3666/? D/CompatibilityInfo: applicationScale - 1.0
06-23 22:40:00.825 4878-8858/? I/Places: Converted 3 out of 3 WiFi scans
06-23 22:40:00.833 3649-10304/? D/SamsungAlarmManager: setInexact Intent (T:2/F:0/AC:false) 20170623T224600 - CU:10015/CP:4878
06-23 22:40:00.837 4878-18241/? W/ctxmgr: [AclManager]No 2 for (accnt=account#1333845215#, com.google.android.gms(10015):UserLocationProducer, vrsn=11055000, 0, 3pPkg = null ,  3pMdlId = null ,  pid = 4878). Was: 2 for 1, account#1333845215#
06-23 22:40:00.838 4878-18241/? W/ctxmgr: [AclManager]No 2 for (accnt=account#-1050787121#, com.google.android.gms(10015):UserLocationProducer, vrsn=11055000, 0, 3pPkg = null ,  3pMdlId = null ,  pid = 4878). Was: 2 for 1, account#-1050787121#
06-23 22:40:00.843 3649-17045/? I/SamsungAlarmManager: setLocked to kernel - T:2 / 20170623T224001, SetElapsed=1128273894, nowELAPSED=1128272765
06-23 22:40:00.844 3649-17045/? D/SamsungAlarmManager: setExact Listener (T:3/F:1/AC:false) 20170623T224600 - CU:10015/CP:4878
06-23 22:40:00.844 3649-5184/? D/SamsungAlarmManager: Cancel Alarm calling from uid:10015 pid :4878 / listener:android.app.IAlarmListener$Stub$Proxy@872b235
06-23 22:40:00.846 4878-21690/? I/GCoreUlr: Successfully inserted 1 locations
06-23 22:40:00.846 3649-5184/? I/SamsungAlarmManager: setLocked to kernel - T:2 / 20170623T224001, SetElapsed=1128273895, nowELAPSED=1128272768
06-23 22:40:00.850 3649-5170/? D/SamsungAlarmManager: setExact Listener (T:3/F:1/AC:false) 20170623T224901 - CU:10015/CP:4878
06-23 22:40:00.930 3649-3850/? D/WifiStateMachine: Current network is: "xxxxxxxxxx" , ID is: 4
06-23 22:40:01.973 3649-3774/? D/SamsungAlarmManager: Expired : 4
06-23 22:40:01.973 3649-3774/? I/SamsungAlarmManager: setLocked to kernel - T:2 / 20170623T224030, SetElapsed=1128302704, nowELAPSED=1128273895
06-23 22:40:01.973 3649-3774/? V/SamsungAlarmManager: Sending to uid : 10275 action=null alarm=Alarm{edc1358 type 0 when 1498254001973 com.antivirus}
06-23 22:40:01.975 3649-3666/? D/CompatibilityInfo: mCompatibilityFlags - 0
06-23 22:40:01.975 3649-3666/? D/CompatibilityInfo: applicationDensity - 640
06-23 22:40:01.975 3649-3666/? D/CompatibilityInfo: applicationScale - 1.0
06-23 22:40:01.979 3649-3845/? D/CompatibilityInfo: mCompatibilityFlags - 0
06-23 22:40:01.979 3649-3845/? D/CompatibilityInfo: applicationDensity - 640
06-23 22:40:01.979 3649-3845/? D/CompatibilityInfo: applicationScale - 1.0
06-23 22:40:01.991 23705-25628/? I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
06-23 22:40:01.991 23705-25628/? I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
06-23 22:40:01.992 3134-3639/? D/EnterpriseController: netId is 0
06-23 22:40:01.992 3134-3639/? D/Netd: getNetworkForDns: using netid 636 for uid 10275
06-23 22:40:01.992 3134-3639/? D/DnsProxyListener: DNSDBG::dns addrinfo af 0
06-23 22:40:02.644 23705-25628/? D/~!ETPushService: POST Response: {"user_id":"0e7fda7c-e331-11e6-9cfa-22000b760996","session_id":"2b872ee6-585b-11e7-ba02-22000bdb4872"}
06-23 22:40:02.668 3649-3666/? W/ActivityManager: Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
06-23 22:40:02.852 3649-17042/? D/CustomFrequencyManagerService: releaseDVFSLockLocked : Getting Lock type frm List : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 1896000  uid : 1000  pid : 3649  tag : com.enhance.gameservice@1
06-23 22:40:03.006 3649-29659/? V/WindowManager: Relayout Window{ee05028d0 u0 SurfaceView - com.package.app/com.package.app.screens.MyActivity}: viewVisibility=0 req=1080x1920 WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(1080x1920) gr=#800033 ty=1001 fl=#4218 pfl=0x10040 fmt=4 naviIconColor=0}
06-23 22:40:03.038 25516-25516/? D/SurfaceView: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][1080,1920] newFrame=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x1 surface={Surface(name=null)/@0x55fcfdd isValid=true 543290612224}
06-23 22:40:03.054 3649-29656/? D/WindowManager: finishDrawingWindow: Window{ee05028d0 u0 SurfaceView - com.package.app/com.package.app.screens.MyActivity} mDrawState=READY_TO_SHOW
06-23 22:40:03.072 3098-3164/? I/Layer: [com.package.app/com.package.app.screens.MyActivity] addSyncPoint start
06-23 22:40:03.072 3098-3164/? I/Layer: [com.package.app/com.package.app.screens.MyActivity] addSyncPoint end
06-23 22:40:03.072 3098-3164/? I/Layer: [com.package.app/com.package.app.screens.MyActivity] addSyncPoint start
06-23 22:40:03.072 3098-3164/? I/Layer: [com.package.app/com.package.app.screens.MyActivity] addSyncPoint end
06-23 22:40:03.158 3649-5036/? D/WindowManager: finishDrawingWindow: Window{a18840ed0 u0 com.package.app/com.package.app.screens.MyActivity} mDrawState=DRAW_PENDING
06-23 22:40:03.160 25516-25516/? D/ViewRootImpl@801a4c4[MyActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
06-23 22:40:03.160 25516-25516/? V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@f516b20 nm : com.package.app ic=null

======ok from here===========

06-23 22:40:03.162 25516-25516/? D/MyActivity: Query inventory finished.
```

Answer (score 1):

One workaround you may try is to disable `instant run` as seen in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37460527/5832311).

```
Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run and uncheck Enable Instant Run
```

You may also check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28678984/5832311) which has similar issue with yours. Maybe the problem was caused from a background image on the root of the layout containing the listview that was too big.